# Gideros GTween Event Listener

Tags: gideros

I'm trying a GTween example from the following link

[Gideros GTween with Easing](http://appcodingeasy.com/Gideros-Mobile/Gideros-GTween-with-easing#disqus_thread)

The example doesn't work out of the box, so I dug into the source code of GTween and added the following lines to my example in order to allow event dispatching.

```
local tween = GTween.new(jewel, 2, animProperties, gtweenProperties)
tween.suppressEvents = false -- New Line #1
tween.dispatchEvents = true  -- New Line #2
tween:addEventListener('complete', function()
    stage:removeChild(jewel)
    jewel = nil
end)
```

However, the app crashes. I tried commenting the following line in `gtween.lua`

```
self:dispatchEvent(Event.new(name))
```

and the app doesn't crash, however the callbacks aren't invoked (obviously, why would it?)

This is the stack trace from the app.

```
gtween.lua:445: attempt to call method 'dispatchEvent' (a boolean value)
stack traceback:
    gtween.lua:445: in function 'dispatchEvt'
    gtween.lua:255: in function 'setPosition'
    gtween.lua:86: in function <gtween.lua:74>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I'm not sure if this is a bug on Gideros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just tried with the latest gideros' [gtween](https://github.com/gideros/GTween) (note that it is edited 10 days ago), and use this sample (i took the sample from your link and add sprite definition, also include a image file in project) and it works(the callback is called) :

```
local animate = {}
animate.y = 100
animate.x = 100
animate.alpha = 0.5
animate.scaleX = 0.5
animate.scaleY = 0.5
animate.rotation = math.random(0, 360)
local properties = {}
properties.delay = 0
properties.ease = easing.inElastic
properties.dispatchEvents = true

local sprite = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("box.png"))  -- ADD THIS
stage:addChild(sprite) -- ADD THIS
local tween = GTween.new(sprite, 10, animate, properties)

tween:addEventListener("complete", function()
    stage:removeChild(sprite)
    sprite = nil
end)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried by copying the example and it worked, not sure why it didn't work before. Thanks for your time.